# A simple String class and its special member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, classes, constructor, overloading

I am learning the behavior of C++'s special member function, using a naive `String` class as example. (The code is modified from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehMg6zvXuMY&t=468s)) Here is the implementation `so-question.cpp`:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class String {
private:
  uint32_t size;
  char *buffer;

public:
  String() {
    cout << "Default No-Parameter Constructor" << endl;
    this->size = 0;
    this->buffer = nullptr;
  }

  String(const char *name) {
    cout << "Parameterized Constructor" << endl;
    this->size = std::strlen(name);
    this->buffer = new char[this->size];
    memcpy(this->buffer, name, this->size);
  }

  String(const String &other) {
    cout << "Copy Construtor" << endl;
    this->size = other.size;
    this->buffer = new char[this->size];
    memcpy(this->buffer, other.buffer, this->size);
  }

  String &operator=(const String &other) {
    cout << "Copy Assignment Operator" << endl;
    if (this != &other) {
      // The buffer size of `this` is different from the `other`'s. So we need
      // to delete `this` and reallocate memory for `this` with the size of
      // `other`.
      delete[] this->buffer;

      this->size = other.size;
      this->buffer = new char[this->size];
      memcpy(this->buffer, other.buffer, this->size);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  String(String &&other) {
    cout << "Move Constructor" << endl;
    this->size = other.size;
    /**
     * In the copy constructor, we have to allocate memory.
     * In the move constructor, we don't have to allocate any more memory. We
     * just have to change a couple of variables so it's very efficient.
     */
    this->buffer = other.buffer;

    /**
     * NOTE: Here, the destructor of "other" will deallocate "other.buffer" and
     * we've stolen the buffer so we don't want that to happen. So to deal
     * with this all we have to do is set "other.buffer" to point to
     * nullptr. And it is safe to delete a nullptr.
     */
    other.size = 0;
    other.buffer = nullptr;
  }

  String &operator=(String &&other) {
    cout << "Move Assignment Operator" << endl;
    if (this != &other) {
      this->size = other.size;
      /**
       * Here, the object `buffer` to which `this` points, needs to be freed up,
       * because `this` is going to point to `other`'s memory. If it's not done,
       * then we have a memory leak.
       */
      delete[] this->buffer;

      this->buffer = other.buffer;

      other.size = 0;
      other.buffer = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  ~String() {
    cout << "Destructor: ";
    // NOTE: a potential bug is here. If `this` has pointed to a nullptr and
    // size is non-zero, then it causes error:
    // Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < this->size; ++i) {
      cout << this->buffer[i];
    }
    cout << '\n';
    delete[] this->buffer;
  }

  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const String &test);
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const String &test) {
  out << "String: ";
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < test.size; ++i) {
    out << test.buffer[i] << ' ';
  }
  return out;
}

String get_String() { return String(); }
```

The `String` class can be tested with the following code:

```
int main() {
  String test1;
  test1 = get_String();
  String test2{"test2"};
  String test3{test2};
  cout << "test1: " << test1 << endl;
  test1 = test3;
  cout << "test2: " << test2 << endl;
  cout << "test3: " << test3 << endl;
  cout << "test1: " << test1 << endl;
  vector<String> vec;
  vec.push_back(String("rvalue"));
  vec.push_back(test1);
  cout << "vec[0] " << vec[0] << endl;
  cout << "vec[1] " << vec[1] << endl;
  cout << '\n';

  cout << "Test move-from object:\n";
  test2 = std::move(test1);
  cout << "test2: " << test2 << endl;
  cout << "test1: " << test1 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And the output message is:

```
Default No-Parameter Constructor
Default No-Parameter Constructor
Move Assignment Operator
Destructor: 
Parameterized Constructor
Copy Construtor
test1: String: 
Copy Assignment Operator
test2: String: t e s t 2 
test3: String: t e s t 2 
test1: String: t e s t 2 
Parameterized Constructor
Move Constructor
Destructor: 
Copy Construtor
Copy Construtor
Destructor: rvalue
vec[0] String: r v a l u e 
vec[1] String: t e s t 2 

Test move-from object:
Move Assignment Operator
test2: String: t e s t 2 
test1: String: 
Destructor: rvalue
Destructor: test2
Destructor: test2
Destructor: test2
```

And the code can be run with the command `g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -std=gnu++17 so-question.cpp && ./a.out`.

The result looks good and makes sense to me.
However, I have one question, is it true that in theory and in practice that when using move constructor and move assignment operator, the move-from object shall be invalid. I am asking this because I am just wondering what if I would like to have two objects points to the same memory location. For example,

```
String test1{"apple"};
String test2;
test2 = std::move(test1);
```

`test1` becomes invalid after it's moved. But what if I want both `test1` and `test2` both points to the same string in memory `apple`. (copy can't be used here because then it will not be the same memory) This can be done by changing the code in move assignment operator. But does it violate some software design pattern and should be avoided or there's a known method to address this behavior? Thank you.

**Update:**  Fix the code to make it as minimum reproducible.

Comment: The specification for "moved-from" states is that they are valid, it is just that it is not specified what they ought to be - making it author's choice. They must be destructible and reassignable. But it might be illegal to call some of the regular functions of the moved-from object.

Comment: When you post a question on Code Review we want to see as much of it as possible, such as include files and any `using` statements. I suspect the code contains `using namespace std;` but I can't be sure and that is something I would want to comment on. It is actually best to provide the code as files so that we might be able to test it ourselves. Right now the code is very hard to review.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the question to make it more complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer to your question

> is it true that in theory and in practice that when using move constructor and move assignment operator, the move-from object shall be invalid.

No, the moved-from object must still be *valid*, however its contents are allowed to be *undefined*. So for your class:

```
String test1{"apple"};
String test2{std::move(test1)};
std::cout << test1;
```

The printing to `std::cout` should still work. However, it is allowed to print "a p p l e", "" or "w h a t e v e r". You chose to set `size` to zero and `buffer` to `nullptr`, which is valid.

The reason why it must be valid is that the object `test1` is still alive here, and at some point its destructor will be called.

> But what if I want both `test1` and `test2` both points to the same string in memory apple. (copy can't be used here because then it will not be the same memory) This can be done by changing the code in move assignment operator. But does it violate some software design pattern and should be avoided or there's a known method to address this behavior?

Then `test1` would not be valid anymore, as both its destructor and that of `test2` would try to `delete[]` the same memory, which is not valid.

## A more elegant way to move

The move constructor and move assignment operator become more elegant to write if you implement a `swap()` member function first, which in turn uses `std::swap()` on the member variables, and by using default member initializers:

```
class String {
    std::size_t size = 0;
    char *buffer = nullptr;

public:
    String() {
        std::cout << "Default No-Parameter Constructor\n";
        // Nothing to do anymore!
    }
    
    String(String &&other) {
        std::cout << "Move Constructor\n";
        swap(other);
    }
    
    String &operator=(String &&other) {
        std::cout << "Move Assignment Operator\n";
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }
    
    void swap(String& other) {
        std::swap(size, other.size);
        std::swap(buffer, other.buffer);
    }
    …
};
```

You no longer have to check if `this == &other`, as `std::swap()` will do the right thing if it swaps the same member variables. The move constructor's body will run after it initialized `size` and `buffer`, so `other` will end up with `0` and `nullptr`. The move assignment operator will swap the two strings. As mentioned above, that's also valid. The destructor of `other` will then take care of deleting the old string.

## Unnecessary use of `this->`

You almost never have to write `this->` in C++. I would just remove it everywhere, as it just adds noise.

## Prefer `'\n'` over `std::endl`

[Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually not necessary and might impact performance.

## Use `std::size_t` for sizes, counts and indices

The return value of [`std::strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) is a [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). Make sure you store your string's size in a variable of that type as well, otherwise you can run into problems if you ever try to store a string that is longer than a `std::uint32_t` can represent.

It is good practice to always use `std::size_t` for anything that deals with the size of arrays or objects in memory, as well as counts and indices related to those.

Comment: I tried your code. But Move Assignment Operator doesn't do thing right. The moved-from object still holds the value. Eg, when `String test_apple{"apple"}; String test_orange{"orange"}; test_orange = std::move(test_apple);`, `test_apple` still holds the value of `test_orange`. I think `test_apple` needs to direct to `nullptr`.

Comment: `other.size = 0;` and `other.buffer = nullptr;` are still needed after `swap(other);` is called in move assignment operator.

Comment: It doesn't matter what `test_apple` holds after being moved from; you shouldn't use it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

[Don't `using namespace std;`](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4850040), as that can be harmful.

Instead, write out `std::uint32_t`, `std::cout`, `std::memcpy` etc. in full.  Maintainers (future you, perhaps) will thank you for being clear which identifiers you're using, and you'll save yourself from embarrassment when the standard library adds more identifiers.

---

Don't mix diagnostic messages with output.

We should be using `std::clog` for these messages so they don't end up being processed by the consumer of the program.

---

Use initializers for class data members.

The constructors here allow the members to default-initialise, then assign values.  Instead, we should be using the constructor's initializer list to populate these.

---

Use a larger indentation.

2 spaces per level is hard to distinguish.  Most style guides recommend at least 4; Linux kernel style uses tabs instead (normally 8 per level).

An advantage of the larger indents is that they alert you to deeply-nested control structures - normally a sign that the code needs refactoring for easier comprehension.

---

And everything mentioned in [G. Sliepen's review](/a/283891/75307).

Comment: I suspect that the `using namespace std;` is in a header file, which is even worse.

Comment: Thanks. When you say `Use initializers for class data members.`, do you mean doing something like:
```
  String(const String &other) : size{other.size} {
    cout << "Copy Construtor" << endl;
    // this->size = other.size;
    this->buffer = new char[this->size];
    memcpy(this->buffer, other.buffer, this->size);
  }
```

Comment: Yes - though I would probably add `buffer{new char[other.size]}` to the initializer list, too.  And the default constructor (without logging) would be simply `String() : size{0}, buffer{} {}`.